# Back gesture in Flutter inAppWebView not working on Android

Tags: android, flutter, gesture, flutter-inappwebview

My inAppWebView recognises the Back and Forward gestures (swipe in from left/right edge) fine on iOS and automatically performs the goBack/goForward accordingly (no code added for that).

But on Android it simply does nothing – it does not react to swiping in from left/right edge at all.

Is there anything one needs to do / set up to make this work also on Android?

My structure is: SafeArea -> Scaffold -> Container -> Expanded -> Container -> InAppWebView

No explicit or custom Gesture Recognizers anywhere.

I tried to use the inAppWebView property "gestureRecognizers" - but without any effect. Whatever gesture recognizers I drop in there, the inAppWebView behaves exactly the same. So that property to me seems to do nothing at all.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **android:windowSwipeToDismiss="true"**

In **AndroidManifest.xml** add the following attribute to your application tag:

**Code:**

```
class MyInAppWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyInAppWebViewState createState() => _MyInAppWebViewState();
}

class _MyInAppWebViewState extends State<MyInAppWebView> {
  late InAppWebViewController _webViewController;
  bool _canGoBack = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (_canGoBack) {
          _webViewController.goBack();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('InAppWebView')),
        body: InAppWebView(
          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('https://www.youtube.com')),
          onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
            _webViewController = controller;
          },
          onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
            setState(() {
              _canGoBack = true;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I've seen this suggestion while searching for answers – but this deals with the Android back button, not the back gesture (swiping in from the left edge of the screen).

With your method (besides having to swap the two returns) it works fine when I tap the actual back button on Android. But the back gesture still does nothing.

Comment: @Johannes Tiefenbrunner
Kindly Check I will Update My Answer Hope So This Working Fine for you

Comment: Hey, many thanks for taking the time! Unfortunately this also does not solve the issue  As said, the back button works fine, it's the swipe that is my issue. And "windowSwipeToDismiss" unfortunately does nothing to change this. For one, "true" seams to be the default anyway (I only find lots of examples that set it to false to avoid this behaviour, especially on wear OS apps), but more so, according to Android Studio this flag is currently deprecated and does nothing ("@deprecated Swipe-to-dismiss isn't functional anymore."). I tried it anyway and it did not change anything.

Comment: I am so sorry: I was not aware that this feature (back gesture) is only available in Android API >=33. Once I ran the app in a simulator with that API level your solution worked fine! Thank you!
PS: The inAppWebView's controller actually has a method canGoBack()...